# calculate the principal part of $\tan(z)$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

calculate the principal part of $\tan(z)$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

of course $\tan(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}.$ Because $\cos(z)$ is of order 1 in  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ we know that our primal part must look like:

$c_{-1}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^{-1}$.

The main problem here is that i don't seem to get how to write the sine and cosine. Are there any neat tricks to see this?

Kees

Comment: Some English math terminology fixes: Principal part, not primal part, and "at $\pi/2$", not "in $\pi/2$".

Comment: thanks, my textbook is dutch so these mistakes can be made fast :)

Comment: More terminology fixes: "sine," not "sinus," and "cosine," not "cosinus."

Comment: To get the principal part of $\tan(z)$ you only need to compute $\lim_{z\to\pi/2}(z-\pi/2)\tan(z)=\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\frac{(z-\pi/2)}{\cos(z)}=\lim_{z\to\pi/2}\frac{1}{-\sin(z)}=-1$. The existence of this limit tells you that $(z-\pi/2)\tan(z)$ is analytic (removable singularity) at $z=\pi/2$ and that the principal part of $\tan(z)$ is $-1/(z-\pi/2)$.

Comment: hmmm i haven't heard of this trick. If one wants to calculate principal parts of a function at a certain point c, it is enough to calculate $\lim_{z \rightarrow c}(z-c)f(z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the taylor series (which equals the function because these are analytic):

$f(z) = f(c) + f'(c) (z-c) + \frac{f''(c)}{2} (z-c)^2 + \cdots$

Use $c = \pi/2$.

$\cos(z) = \cos(\pi/2) - \sin(\pi/2)(z-c) + \ldots = -(z-c) + \ldots$

$\sin(z) = \sin(\pi/2) + \ldots = 1 + \ldots$

Now you can get the principal part by dividing these (you don't need any more terms than I gave to know the degree $-1$ part).

Comment: hmmm i already thought about this, but does one not get any trouble in the denominator. We can't just ignore the restterms right?

Comment: @KeesTil Sure you can. Factor $z-c$ out of the denominator, and then it's $\frac{1}{z-c}\frac{1+o(1)}{-1 + o(1)}$ and the $\frac{1+o(1)}{-1+o(1)} = -1 + o(1)$ (also/alternatively, that part is analytic near $c$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{z\to \pi/2}(z-\pi/2)\frac{\sin z}{\cos z} = \lim_{z\to \pi/2}  \frac{z-\pi/2}{\cos z - \cos (\pi/2)}\sin z$$ $$ = \frac{1}{\cos '(\pi/2)}\cdot 1= -1.$$ It follows that $\tan z$ has a simple pole at $0,$ hence the prinicpal part is $-1/(z-\pi/2).$

Comment: hmmm i haven't heard of this trick. If one wants to calculate principal parts of a function at a certain point c, it is enough to calculate limz→c(z−c)f(z)?

Or is this only usefull if you have a simple pole?

Comment: It works for simple poles only. With a higher order pole, the limit will be $\infty.$